# Am I missing something in this question or is it really one-line? (Fubini or not)

Tags: integration, measure-theory, proof-verification

> If $h(x,y) = f(y)g(x)$ and $f$ is a function on $(X, \mu)$ and $g $ on $(Y, \nu)$, then $\int_{X \times Y} h d(\mu \times \nu) = \int_Y g d\nu \int_X f d\mu$ and $h$ is $\mu \times \nu $ integrable.

Isn't the whole thing just

$$\int_{X \times Y} h(x,y) d(\mu \times \nu) = \int_{X \times Y} f(y)g(x) d\mu d\nu = \int_X  \int_Y f(y) g(x) d\mu d\nu = \int_Y g d\nu \int_X f d\mu$$

The second equality is Fubini and the third equality is Tonelli. The first equality is replacement from the information given in the question.

**EDIT**: Should mention that the last line implies $\int h < \infty$ since $f$ and $g$ are integrable.

Comment: The last equality follows simply from the definition of integrals. But Fubini's theorem has prerequisites which you did not check. Apart from this, your proof is correct.

Comment: @PhoemueX, oh that being $h$ is measurable? So if I show $h$ is measurable, I can just add that one line and I am good? For some reason I thought integrable = measurable.

Comment: Yes. Furthermore, you would need that $\mu,\nu$ are $\sigma$-finite. But actually, you can drop that assumption in your case since integrable functions vanish outside of a $\sigma$-finite set. Finally, Fubini needs that $h$ is measurable and that $\int |h(x,y)| \,d(\mu\times\nu) <\infty$. This second condition can be verified using Tonellis theorem which only needs measurability.

Comment: @PhoemueX, didn't I prove (until $h \in M$  is shown) $\int |h| < \infty$ since $h \in L^1 \iff |h| \in L^1$. I am using integrable for $L^1$ ( should've mentioned that).